# MySQL Server not starting with MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

My MySQL Server wont start anymore on MAMP. The solutions I found online said, that I should first quit MAMP, quit the MYSQL process, and start MAMP again.
But there is no MySQL process running in my situation, so this didn't work. Do you have any idea, what else could be the process?

You can find my error log here:

> 2017-01-20 21:40:03 7fff79bb0000  InnoDB: Operating system error
>   number 2 in a file operation. InnoDB: The error means the system
>   cannot find the path specified. InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB,
>   remember that you must create InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB
>   does not create them. InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table
>   tablespace file ./yunityproject_wordpress/wp_comments.ibd InnoDB: We
>   do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>   InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log
>   to it. InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld: InnoDB: 1) If
>   there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot InnoDB:
>   open the file, you should modify the permissions. InnoDB: 2) If the
>   table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup, InnoDB: then
>   you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal InnoDB:
>   crash recovery and ignore that table. InnoDB: 3) If the file system or
>   the disk is broken, and you cannot remove InnoDB: the .ibd file, you
>   can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf InnoDB: and force InnoDB
>   to continue crash recovery here. 170120 21:40:04 mysqld_safe mysqld
>   from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

Comment: The MySQL process is inside mamp not at the os level

Answer (score 2):

Just had this issue.  Turns out a mysql.pid file was missing from the mamp\tmp\mysql\ folder.  uninstalled, reinstalled and everything works.  just make sure you delete the old mamp folder.

[coincidence? my mamp-pro license just expired and then this issue happened]